# C# Подскажите с организацией логики обновления БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, datagridview, datatable

Всем привет =) Я парсю с сайта обновляемые данные [image: Данные]

и храню их в DataTable данные обновляются каждую секунду и в случайных местах, по ходу парсинга строки с сайта могут удаляться или появляться новые, то есть привязку не сделать к id или индексу. С бд не так много опыта, с ними практически не работал, то что пробовал не вышло. Так как данные не стабильны, каждый раз новые  можно было с бд выводить их в datagridview и очищать бд и заполнять бд заного, при обновление таким подходом разница в datagridview не заметно, кажется что это живая таблица, то есть обновление как с сайта. Я пробовал так делать без циклов и т.п меня это вполне устроило. Но в основном коде не вышло так сделать..
Бд заполняется по принципу

```
for(int i =0; i <++)
 {
     for(int s =0; s <++) 
     {
     DataTableOne.Rows.Add("Здесь заношу данные");
     }
 }
dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTableOne; dataGridView1.Update(); 
DataTableOne.Clear(); //Было бы идеально, если так бд очищалась бы и заполнялась заново.
```

При активном изменение данных в datagrid кажется что это живая таблица, но вместо этого DataTableOne.Clear(); очищает бд и данные с datagrid тоже удаляются.
Ещё пробовал делать с подменной таблицей так

```
 flagRateTable = true;
    for(int i =0; i <++)
     {
         for(int s =0; s <++) 
         {
         DataTableOne.Rows.Add("Здесь заношу данные");
         DataTableTwo.Rows.Add("Здесь заношу данные");
         }
     }
if (flagRateTable)
                    {
                        DataTableTwo.Clear();
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTableOne; dataGridView1.Update();                    
                        flagRateTable = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataTableOne.Clear();
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTableTwo; dataGridView1.Update();                    
                        flagRateTable = true;
                    }
```

По логике если flagRateTable true очищаю вторую бд и вывожу в dataGridView1 DataTableOne
если flagRateTable false очищаю первую бд и вывожу в dataGridView1 DataTableTwo.
По идее должно всё работать, но вместо этого у меня отображаются обе бд, то есть как в первом примере с очисткой с dataGridView1 удаляются все отображаемые данные, то в втором примере у меня отображаются обе таблицы, поочередно очищаются и отображаются вместе.
Подскажите с логикой и как лучше обновлять подобные бд.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что проблема - исключительно в том, чтобы обновлять только некоторые данные в DataGrid, и тогда будет создаваться спечатление, что это "живая таблица"?

Comment: @S.H. Не которые данные обновлять мало смыла, так как в каждой ячейке данные меняются, я могу оставить столбец в котором изменения не происходят, но к примеру эта строчка удалится с сайта и у меня в программе тоже удалится, так как в бд заношу данные повторно с сайта после заполнения бд. Я думаю что лучше было бы обновлять бд целиком, и у меня это не получается.

Comment: @S.H. Для сравнения это как если я в бд держал время с разных поясов и мне нужно было динамически отображать его в datagridview, только в моём случае к индексу ни к какому не привязаться. Что было бы оптимально как я думаю обновлять  всю бд целиком после выполнения цикла, но в таком случае в бд остаются данные и они заполняются повторно, а если я использую очистку бд, то в datagrid все отображаемые данные стираются...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DoubleBufferedDataGridView dataGridView;
    Button updateButton;

    DataTable dataTable1;
    DataTable dataTable2;

    Random random = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView = new DoubleBufferedDataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 200 };
        updateButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Update", Top = dataGridView.Bottom + 20 };

        updateButton.Enabled = false;
        updateButton.Click += UpdateButton_Click;
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataTable1 = new DataTable();

        dataTable1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dataTable1.Columns.Add("value", typeof(double));

        dataTable2 = dataTable1.Clone();

        await FillDataTable(dataTable1);
        dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable1;

        await FillDataTable(dataTable2);
        updateButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private Task FillDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            dataTable.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                dataTable.Rows.Add(random.Next(), random.NextDouble());
        });
    }

    private async void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateButton.Enabled = false;

        if (dataGridView.DataSource == dataTable1)
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable2;
            await FillDataTable(dataTable1);
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable1;
            await FillDataTable(dataTable2);
        }

        updateButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Два дататейбла. На старте приложения заполняется первый и привязывается к гриду. Тем временем заполняется второй.

При нажатии на кнопку они меняются местами. И снова происходит заполнение данными другого дататейбла.

Я меняю доступность кнопки (свойство `Enabled`), чтобы нельзя было её нажать, пока новые данные не загружены полностью.

В методе `FillDataTable` реализуйте свой код получения новых данных и занесения в `DataTable`.

---

Грид с двойной буферизацией:

```
public class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered => true;
}
```

Используемые пространства имён:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: не хватает только отлова возможных исключений в `async void` методе

Comment: @Alexander Petrov и aepot - спасибо за прекрасный ответ и комментарий!

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы =) Всё работает как нужно, при обновление грида, даже не чувствуется разницы) + скорость вывода уменьшилась на 10 секунд)

Comment: @ИванРудаков галочку ставить не забывайте. :)

Comment: @aepot сразу поставил как проверил, ответ очень полезный, я вообще про другое думал, а тут выход оригинальный такой =)

Comment: @ИванРудаков не поставили :) галочка чуть ниже стрелочек для голосования.

Comment: @aepot стоит там моя галочка =) если повторно нажму будет отмена, а этого делать не нужно =) Да я нажимал снизу галочку)

Comment: @ИванРудаков вижу, теперь стоит. :)

Comment: Подскажите в данной теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278954/c-datagridview-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-da как начал бд использовать у меня неправильно стал форматироваться грид и индекс не могу получить выделенной строки.