# C# DataGridview форматирует все строки вместо нужных после загрузки данных из datable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, форматирование

Всем привет datagridview форматирует все строки вместо тех что указаны в условии.  У меня есть бд DataTabe из неё загружаю данные  dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable; а заполняю datable так  dataTable.Rows.Add("Здесь какие данные") при запуске в load формы инициализирую столбцы

```
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("1");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("2");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("3");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("4");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("5");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("6");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("7");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("8");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("9");
            dataTable1.Columns.Add("10");
            dataTable2 = dataTable1.Clone();
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DataPropertyName = "1";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column2"].DataPropertyName = "2";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column3"].DataPropertyName = "3";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column4"].DataPropertyName = "4";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column5"].DataPropertyName = "5";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column6"].DataPropertyName = "6";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column7"].DataPropertyName = "7";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column8"].DataPropertyName = "8";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column9"].DataPropertyName = "9";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column10"].DataPropertyName = "10";
```

В событии CellFormatung

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                if (e.Value.GetType() != typeof(System.DBNull))
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(e.Value) == "1")
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
                        {
                            //dataGridView1[i, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(69, 84, 78);
                            //dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(69, 84, 78);
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(69, 84, 78);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

При форматирование у меня весь datagridview форматируется [image: datagrid]
а должны форматироваться только те строки где ячейка равна 1, после того как добавил datable такое началось. До того как не использовал бд, форматировалось всё хорошо [image: до использования datatable]

И ещё не могу теперь взять индекс выделенной строки в datagridview

```
string Name = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
```

Вот такие проблемки начались когда начал загружать данные из datatable.
Эту бд привязывать как нужно или почему код перестал работать?

Comment: То есть вы зачем-то повторяете заголовки колонок через одну строку? Используйте [Alternating Row](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-alternating-row-styles-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) для стилизации.

Comment: Если вы хотите изменить целиком **строку**, то зачем используете событие `CellFromatting`? Оно предназначено для одной **ячейки**. Возьмите событие `RowPrePaint`. Но лучше смотрите первый коммент.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо помогли всё работает) Почитал то что вы посоветовали) И про заголовки dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DataPropertyName = "1"; я их не повторяю, а связываю их с dataGridView1 и тем самым они наследуют все параметры что я для них настроил в конструкторе, до этого пока так не делал приходилось кодом всё прописывать, а теперь эти 10 строк облегчают подход к этому =) И как вам засчитать ответ, подобающей галочки нет, вы отвечали комментарием, прикрепите ответ, я галочку поставлю)

Comment: Напишите ответ сами. И потом примите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(69, 84, 78);
            }
         }
```

Событие RowPrePaint при отрисовке строк помогло, теперь всё работает корректно